# Dynamically assigning the ref to textarea, but it's returning the last field value.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

As stated in title,
Only the last form of the array returned value. Other form returned empty. 
Need help understanding how:

```
addComment(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const commentContent = this.refs.commentContent.value;

    console.log(commentContent);
    this.refs.commentContent.value = '';

}

renderArticleList() {
   return (
       this.props.articles.map( (article) => {
          const articleId = article._id;
          return (
             <div key={articleId}>

                <form onSubmit={this.addComment.bind(this)}>
                   <textarea ref="commentContent"/>
                   <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                </form>

             </div>
          )
       })
    )
 }
```

Code Solutions to solve problem greatly appreciated. 
Links to help understand and solve the problem also great.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you trying to populate the textarea with content from your props?

Comment: Your problem here will be related to using the same ref for every form, how will the function know which one you are talking about. I would suggest reading this page https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html for guidance on using forms within your components. You may be better of using state, i.e. have a state value that is set from any of the forms, and then the onSubmit function looks at that state value.

Comment: `ref` is scoped to the component, so as long as you're using the same `ref` name, you'll have one reference. In your case, your references are overriding one another and you're only left with the last one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason is, you are using the same `ref` for all the `input` element, to make the `ref` unique, append the index of form with the `ref`, and pass that index to `submit` function, and use that index to access the input field value, Try this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        };
    }

    addComment(i, event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       let ref = 'commentContent'+i;
       console.log('value', this.refs[ref].value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {
              this.props.articles.map( (article,i) => {
                  const articleId = article._id;
                  return (
                    <div key={articleId}>

                      <form onSubmit={this.addComment.bind(this,i)}>
                        <textarea ref={"commentContent"+i}/>
                        <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
                      </form>

                    </div>
                  )
                })
            }
          </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Check the working code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: ''
    };
}

addComment(i, event) {
event.preventDefault();
let ref = 'commentContent'+i;
console.log('value', this.refs[ref].value);
}

render() {
return (<div>
  {[1,2,3].map( (article,i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <form onSubmit={this.addComment.bind(this,i)}>
          <textarea ref={"commentContent"+i}/>
          <button type="submit">Add Comment</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  })}
  </div>
  )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

Check the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fggkdw3/

Comment: Thanks for code help. I used the articleId instead of "i". I removed "i" from (article, i). It still worked.

Comment: yes it will work, it requires any unique id to make the ref unique, but in that case you need to pass this id in submit function instead of i :)